# CUPS HPLIP config problem

Tags: printing, cups

I am trying to connect a HP LaserJet 4 to CUPS/HPLIP. Originally, I was using Raspi OS 11.3 and getting nowhere but eventually discovered "hp-setup" which listed loads of missing dependencies before stating that version 11 was not recognized or supported. I switched to 10.12 and started to make some progress but have stuck at the "Connection" option.  I am using a Centronics to USB adapter. The default connection is "hp". There is no hint as to how to proceed with a usb connection so I tried "hp://LaserJet4".  It accepted that, I then selected "LaserJet 4" as the print driver but "Print a Test Page" failed. I also tried "usb://LaserJet4" and "usb://lp0" (as reported in /dev/usb/) both failed Test Page.

Some history. Until last week when the hdd on my Win10 desk top failed, the printer was connected to that via the usb adaptor using the PCL5 driver. Unfortunately the current version PCL5 or 6 no longer support the LJ4 hence the need for a new connection method.

I am assuming the problem is the entry for "Connection" but maybe there is something else I am missing.

Comment: Have you tried installing the proprietary plugin? A lot of older hp printers need it

Comment: The version of hp-lip in use lists "HP LaserJet 4" as a supported printer. Please can you give me a link and install instructions for the proprietary plugin. "Print a Test Page" produces an error which indicates that a PS page is being sent., possibly from a different driver LJ 4m/P. The printer in question is in my  holiday home. It will be mid July beefore I am able to progress this.